# Desktop Mode problems

Tags: boot, sd-card, ssh, gui

I have run into a quite puzzling problem.

I was fiddling around with the raspi-config settings, and I decided that I'd try running my RPi once with `boot_behaviour` set on Desktop Mode. Upon re-booting, I've come across the problem that, instead of going directly to my Desktop as `startx` would usually do once you're logged in, it instead gave me the Login GUI itself, where I am prompted to input an username and password.

I have tried every possible combination into that login box (nothing works - apart from what you're about to read). But, upon trying the default login "pi", "raspberry", it goes back to command line for a split second, and immediately returns and prompts me to the Login GUI again.

I realize that the easiest way to get around this is to remove the SD card, and re-burn it. Here's the catch: I cannot remove the SD card out of my RPi. My Pi was one of the few where the corner of the SD card was broken, and instead of sending it back, I managed to get a DIY solution to it, but I rather not take my chances.

So, is there any way to fix this annoying problem? Is there a way to get into the SD card data and edit it, or get to a command line somehow without removing the SD card? I have not tried SSH'ing into the RPi, mostly because I'm not sure how to. If the solution truly is SSH'ing into the Pi, could you point me toward a tutorial of sorts that can walk me through this process without any mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually press Ctrl-Alt-(F#) to switch between the console and your X session.  For example: Ctrl-Alt-F2 for new console session, Ctrl-Alt-F7 to return to X

You may have to experiment and try out function key mapping as it can change a bit from system to system.

Comment: Thanks, although I did not try your solution because my problem was fixed by some folks at the RPi Forums, it's very much appreciated. If I run across this problem again, I'll be sure to try this out.